# String array to string with format

Tags: java, android, arrays, string

I have setup 3 text views each set to maximum of 9 chars. The user can edit these text views and save them to file. I first convert the string array to string.

```
   StrLabels[0]=label1.getText().toString();
   StrLabels[1]=label2.getText().toString();        
   StrLabels[2]=label3.getText().toString();    

   StrFile=(StrLabels[0] + StrLabels[1] + StrLabels[2]);

   writeToFile(StrFile);
```

The StrFile saves the 3 string fine but I will also need to reverse the process and read the file. Is there a way separate the each of the StrLabels[] from the StrFile.

Thank you  Gianmarco, here is the final code with your help. I reversed the toBeAdded so it added to the end of the string instead of the front.

```
      String totalString = ""; // initialization of the total string
      String piece = StrLabels[0];


      String toBeAdded = "";
      if(piece.length() < 9){
      int length = piece.length();
      toBeAdded = piece;
              while(length < 9){
              toBeAdded =toBeAdded +"";
              length++;
              }
       } else if(piece.length() > 9){

       throw new IllegalArgumentException ("Error, string longer than 9");
       } else {
       toBeAdded = piece;
       }
       totalString = totalString + toBeAdded;
```

Comment: without some separator between "labels" - no ... better google for `SharedPreferences`

Comment: Yes @Selvin is right  have a look here [getStringSet](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getStringSet%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Set%3Cjava.lang.String%3E%29)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually if you put the three strings plain in the "total" String is difficult to divide back the three original Strings unless you follow one of this method:

## Fixed Length:

Each `String` is fixed in length: this means that separating three (or even more) pieces of the same length from the "total" `String` you will have the original three strings. e.g.:

```
String[] arrayOfStrings = {"abcde", "fghij", "klmno"}; //each string is long 5
String totalString = arrayOfString[0] + arrayOfString[1] + arrayOfString[2]; // parenthesis not needed

// now if I want to came back to the original three I have to do like this:
String[] newArrayOfStrings = new String[3]; // I create a new array that has to be filled with the original 3 strings
newArrayOfStrings[0] = totalString.substring(0,5); //cut the first part, from character number 0 incluse to character number 5 excluse (from 0 to 4)
newArrayOfStrings[1] = totalString.substring(5,10);
newArrayOfStrings[2] = totalString.substring(10,15);

System.out.println(newArrayOfString[0] + newArrayOfString[1] + newArrayOfString[2]); // this will output "abcdefghijklmno"

// you can do that process also with a cycle (if you have more than three strings together

for(int i = 0, i < arrayOfStrings.length ; i++){
    newArrayOfStrings[i] = totalString.substring((i* 5),5+(i*5));
}
```

Now we assume our `String`s are 9 char long and must be 9 char long. If they are shorter we are going to add spaces before the `String`. For this example I am going to use the array of the previous example with a little change.

```
String[] arrayOfStrings = {"abcde", "fghij", "klmnopqrs"};
// first string is long 5, need to be 9
// second string long 5, need to be 9
// third string long 9, that's ok.

String totalString = ""; // initialization of the total string
for(int i = 0; i < arrayOfStrings.length; i++){
    String piece = arrayOfString[i];

    String toBeAdded = "";
    if(piece.length() < 9){
        int length = piece.length();
        toBeAdded = piece;
        while(length < 9){
            toBeAdded = " " + toBeAdded;
            length++;
        }
    } else if(piece.length() > 9){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException ("Error, string longer than 9");
    } else {
        toBeAdded = piece;
    }
    totalString = totalString + toBeAdded;
}

System.out.println(totalString); // this will be "    abcde    fghijklmnopqrs"

// to separate the strings to as the previous example but before adding in the new array you have to remove the white spaces using>
String thisIsTheOneWithoutWhiteSpaces = pieceWithSpaces.trim();
```

## Delimiters:

The second way is using delimiters and then use split. I will add a vertical bar "|" between each string.
The eventuality that the vertical bar is present in one of your line is very small, so you won't need to escape the separator char. If you want to use a common character as separator, you will have to add an escaping char in front of each separator, not to be confused.

```
String[] arrayOfStrings = {"abcde", "fghij", "klmno"}; //each string is long 5
String totalString = arrayOfString[0] + "|" + arrayOfString[1] + "|" + arrayOfString[2]; // the result is abcde|fghij|klmno

//now I split the strings from the total to a new array:
String[] newArrayOfStrings = totalString.split("|");

System.out.println(newArrayOfString[0] + newArrayOfString[1] + newArrayOfString[2]); // this will output "abcdefghijklmno"
```

## Capital Letters:

another way is to use Capital letters to divide the string, but this is more difficult so I will avoid it.

## JSON (from njzk2)

Simply create a `JSONArray`, put your strings in it, call `toString` on the `JSONArray`.
Reverse by parsing the read string in a `JSONArray`

in code (from me) is:

```
String[] arrayOfStrings = {"abcde", "fghij", "klmno"};
JSONArray array = new JSONArray();

for(int i=0; i<arrayOfString.length; i++){
    array.put(arrayOfStrings[i]);
}

String totalString = array.toString();

// to import the string and decode it you have to do this:

JSONArray newArray = new JSONArray(totalString);

// now each element of the array is the same of the starting array "arrayOfString"
```

Comment: I like the fixed length idea. The text view is set up for max of 9 chars but if the user only fills in 4 the fixed length will fail. Can spaces be added to entered text to assure 9 spaces.

Comment: While(lenght<9) is an endless loop.  Length needs updated after toBeAdded="" + toBeAdded.  any thoughts ?

Answer (score 1):

A basic solution would be to use a separator, but that would mean handling situations where your separator is in your string, which means a lot of hassle to make sure it works. A more simple solution is to rely on existing methods.

### JSON

Simply create a `JSONArray`, put your strings in it, call `toString` on the `JSONArray`.

Reverse by parsing the read string in a `JSONArray`

The trivial way of creating your JSONArray is:

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(Arrays.asList(StrLabels));
// The output String is simply
String StrFile = array.toString();
```

### DataOutputStream

When writing to a file, you use a `FileOutputStream`. You can open a `DataOutputStream` on top of that, and use `writeUTF` to write your strings to the file.

Reverse by opening a `DataInputStream` on the file and calling `readUTF`

Comment: nice one! I didn't know that

Answer (score 0):

You can put some special character you chose between those string, or put new line characters before saving them like this( i chose ";" for ex. )

```
     StrFile=(StrLabels[0] +";"+ StrLabels[1] +";"+ StrLabels[2]);
```

and then once you read it from your file, you can use:

```
    strFile.split(";");
```

Which returns you an array of Strings.

Comment: But in this case you should somehow screening this chars inside user-entered strings, because user can easily input ";" chars and in this case result of "strFile.split" will be not that you expect

Answer (score 0):

For example you can use an separator while saving strings:

`StrFile = (StrLabels[0] + "\n" + StrLabels[1] + "\n" + StrLabels[2]);`

and when you readed it from file just do:

`String[] StrLabels = StrFile.split("\n");`

Comment: Your comment to my answer also applies to your answer ;) .